# Matching a pattern in cat/zcat?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I match a more complex pattern when using `cat` or `zcat`? For example, I know I can do this:

```
zcat /var/log/nginx/access.log.*.gz
```

Which will output all the gzipped access logs to stdin.

What if I want a more complex pattern? Say, all the log files that are between 1-15, e.g. something like this pattern:

```
zcat /var/log/nginx/access.log.([1-9]|1[0-5]).gz
```

This results in an `unexpected token` which is obvious, but I'm not sure how I'd escape the regex in this situation? Maybe I need to pipe `ls` output to zcat instead?

Comment: The pattern you used can just be modified very slightly, to `@([1-9]|1[0-5])`, to make it an extglob. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language -- btw, that's not cat/zcat doing the pattern match, it's the shell; globs are extended _by the shell_ before whatever program they're starting is run (on UNIX; on Windows it's done the other way around).

Comment: BTW -- if you want fancier matching that's [a job for `find`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Searching_based_on_names), which supports both glob-style patterns and explicit regular expressions; [`ls` is explicitly not suited to the task](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: (note that `shopt -s extglob` needs to be run before extended globbing expressions will work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of course on specifically what pattern you want to match. For the example you have given of log files 1-15, you could use something like

```
cat /var/log/nginx/access.log.{1..15}.gz
```

which will complain to stderr if any of those numbers don't exist, but it will still concatenate the rest to stdout.

This technique is a "sequence expression" if you want to look it up - it's a part of brace expansion.

Comment: This works well, and yes, it's nice to see the warning but it still concatenating!